# Переход к якорю при заданном base

Tags: html

Можно ли в отдельно взятой ссылке тега `<a>` отключить влияние `<base>`?

Например, в html-документе имеется тег `<base href="http://site.ru/">`, задающий корневой адрес сайта. Так вот, если на странице `some.html` я указываю `<a href="#anchor>Link</a>`, то ссылка будет вести на `http://site.ru/#anchor`, хотя мне нужно перейти на якорь текущей страницы (`http://site.ru/some.html#anchor`). Почему это происходит – понятно, но я бы хотел не указывая путь к `some.html` просто задать `#anchor` и перейти к якорю. Можно это как-то сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не писать путь к `some.html`, то придется использовать JS.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.location.hash='anchor';">Anchor</a>
```

Или так:

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("anchor-test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.location.hash='test';
      e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base